# InputManager automatically removes Wireless Controller from list

Tags: android, joystick

I am trying to handle a ps4 controller thanks to InputManager on an Android device.

The controller connects by Bluetooth to the smartphone with the built-in android interface. On connecting, InputDeviceListener is called and the log displays `onInputDeviceAdded: Wireless Controller` which is normal regarding the following code. But then, after something like 5 secs, `onInputDeviceRemoved` is called for whatever reason! Meaning the controller was removed from the device list and preventing the smartphone from receiving any `KeyEvent`.

It appears the controller is only removed from the InputManager list since it is still paired with the smartphone.

Here is my code :

```
public class activity_test extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = activity_test.class.getSimpleName();

    private InputManager mInputManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

        mInputManager = (InputManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_SERVICE);

        int[] ids = mInputManager.getInputDeviceIds();

        mInputManager.registerInputDeviceListener(new InputManager.InputDeviceListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInputDeviceAdded(int i) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onInputDeviceAdded: "+mInputManager.getInputDevice(i));
            }

            @Override
            public void onInputDeviceRemoved(int i) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onInputDeviceRemoved: "+mInputManager.getInputDevice(i));
            }

            @Override
            public void onInputDeviceChanged(int i) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onInputDeviceChanged: "+mInputManager.getInputDevice(i));
            }
        }, null);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to know what's causing this and avoid it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the code works. I tried it with a Bluetooth keyboard and it works just fine.
It looks like the problem rather comes from the smartphone/Android version which does not support ps4 controller through Bluetooth (I am currently using a Huawei p8 lite 2017, Android 8.0.0).
So the solution I found is connecting both with a OTG cable.